# TextBox showing past entries

Tags: vb.net, textbox, visual-web-developer-2010

I can not get the textbox past entries to go away using the aspx.vb behind page ( can do it on aspx page) Example below

[image: Example]

I have tried both

```
        txt.AutoCompleteType = AutoCompleteType.Disabled
        txt.ViewStateMode = UI.ViewStateMode.Disabled
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add autocomplete="off" attribute to textbox

```
<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="Textbox1" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

or add to to from tag

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
```

using code behind

```
Textbox1.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
```